# Operations on stacks of coins

Tags: algorithm

I'm struggling with a problem from some old programming contest with no result, so I'm asking for help here. Let me describe it below.

At first we have 1<=**n**<=1000 stacks of coins, each of them contains at most 10^9 coins. Then in one move we select the highest stack (if there are many with maximal number of coins, we select one of them) and let's say that it has **m** coins. Then we split it into two stacks containing **m** div 2 and (**m**+1) div 2 coins respectively. We make moves until there are only stacks with 1 coin.

So the input for this problem is a number **n** and then **n** numbers describing initial heights of those stacks. Then there is a number 1<=**q**<=5*10^5 which denotes number of queries. Each query consists of one number 1<=**k**<=10^9. So we have **q** queries, respectively: k_1, k_2,..., k_q and we know that the sum of those numbers is less or equal the number of possible moves until end condition. For number k_1 we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after k_1 moves. For number k_2 we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after **next** k_2 moves, and so on.

This problem would be easy if it wasn't for possible big initial heights of stacks (10^9).

For **example**, we have 3 stacks with 9, 2 and 8 coins respectively, at first. Then for query input (first number is a number q): 3, 1, 2, 3, the correct output is: 4, 3, 2, because after first move we have stacks: 8,5,4,2, after three moves we have: 4,4,4,3,2 (three different heights), and after 1+2+3=6 moves we have: 3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.

Can anybody help? How can I solve this fast? (standard time limit 1sec for one test file and 256MB RAM, something like O(q log q) should be fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using a simple balanced binary search tree and a (slightly optimzed) simulation of the game:

1. The nodes represent the different stack heights. Each of them also contains a counter that represents how many stacks are there of a given height
2. You simulate the game. One step consists of find the maximum height `h` in the BBST, decreasing its counter by one and increasing the counters of `h/2` and `(h+1) / 2` by one. Don't forget to remove nodes with counter 0. An important optimization is that you "fast forward" to the next interesting step. If you have `m` stacks of height `h`, you can process all those at once by removing the node `h` and adding `m` to the nodes `h/2` and `(h+1) / 2`.
   The reason you can do that is because the number of nodes that might be created by a single stack is bounded by `2 * ceil(log_2(10^9)) = 60`.
3. Then after a simulated step, remember the number of nodes in the BBST for the `k_i` to which you skipped.

**Analysis**: You will get at most `O(log H * n)` nodes in your binary search tree, where `H` is the maximum height (`10^9` in your case). Thus operations on the binary search tree take time `O(log (log H * n)) = O(log log H + log n)` You will need at most `O(q + log H * n)` operations because if a query can not be solved by looking at a single node, this means you remove at least one node from the BBST (and there exist only `O(log H * n)` of those). In total, your worst case runtime is `O((q + log H * n) * (log log H + log n))`.

I don't think that can actually be achieved, since in practice you will certainly have a lot less than `O(log H * n)` nodes due to overlaps between the stacks.

Comment: Note that 1<= k_i <= 10^9, and I have q different k_i. Number of simulations in your approach is huge (as is possible number of moves in this game). For one query: 10^9 simulations? This takes too long (although it works if heights are small like 10^6, not 10^9 - this is what I meant writing: "This problem would be.."). Also performing all simulations for a given height in one operation doesn't make this approach fast either (Loren Pechtel's suggestion). I think in this problem we have to forget about simulating, some smart observation is needed.

Comment: @xan: I see. This doesn't make it a lot harder though, you just need to add sweep line to the algorithm

Comment: @xan: Check the edit. Every stack of height `h` will result in at most `O(log h)` noes being created, so it's still `O(q * polylog q)`.

Comment: @xan: Can you link to the problem statement?

Comment: queries are sorted already, please look at the input specification. If I'm not mistaken you described Loren Pechtel's suggestion and I claim that this approach can be also very very slow worst case (it's more tricky than it looks, I'm still trying to estimate complexity). Unfortunately I can't link to the problem statement, because I found it in an old book and had to translate it into English.

Comment: @xan: You will get at most `O(log H * n)` nodes in your binary search tree, where H is the maximum height (10^9 in your case). Thus operations on the binary search tree are bounded by `O(log log H + log n)` You will need at most `O(q + log H * n)` operations because if a query cannot be solve in `O(log log H + log n)`, this means you remove at least one node from the BBST. In total, your worst case runtime is `O(n * log n + (q + log H * n) * (log log H + log n))`

Comment: I think, I'm convinced now. It really should work fast, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you observe this problem more carefully, you will see that you end up having approximately  log(n) different stacks from any stacks, because you divide number of highest stack by 2.

Doing simulation, you can make most of moves in bulk. For example

If highest pile has 100 coins and there are 1000 piles of this kind, you made 1000 moves by making extra 2000 piles of size 50.

You will end up counting number of piles for each of N sized pile. You should use data structure that supports this kind of logic well (key/value store for example)

Comment: The actual bound is `2*log_2(10^9)`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but I see one simplification to the problem that will make modelling it much easier:

You have a choose-a-random-stack in there which messes up modelling.  You don't actually need it, the stacks are identical.  Furthermore, if you have n stacks of the same height you know the next n moves are going to be splitting those stacks.

This also means you don't need to keep track of each stack, simply keep track of how many stacks of a given height you have.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if expressing this more precisely can help (I use java, because I am confortable with that, but you can use whatever you need):

> At first we have 1<=n<=1000 stacks of coins, each of them contains at most 10^9 coins. Then in one move we select the highest stack (if there are many with maximal number of coins, we select one of them) and let's say that it has m coins. Then we split it into two stacks containing m div 2 and (m+1) div 2 coins respectively. We make moves until there are only stacks with 1 coin.

So we have a `SortedSet<Integer> coinStacks` that we know has at most 1000 elements which are at most 10^9:

```java
    assert(coinStacks.size() >= 1, "Too few stacks");
    assert(coinStacks.size() <= 1000, "Too many stacks");
    assert(coinStacks.last() <= 100000000000, "Too large stacks");
```

We also have a function:

```java
void splitBiggestStack(SortedSet<Integer> coinStacks){
    int coinStack = coinStacks.last();
    coinStacks.remove(coinStack);
    coinStacks.add(coinStack/2);
    coinStacks.add(coinStack/2 + coinStack%2);
}
```

We apply the function iteratively on our `coinStacks` until only stacks of size 1 remain:

```java
while(coinStacks.last() > 1)
    splitBiggestStack(coinStacks);
```

All in all:

```java
void iterativeCoinStackReduction(SortedSet<Integer> coinStacks){
    assert(coinStacks.size() >= 1, "Too few stacks");
    assert(coinStacks.size() <= 1000, "Too many stacks");
    assert(coinStacks.last() <= 10000000000, "Too large stacks");

    while(coinStacks.last() > 1)
        splitBiggestStack(coinStacks);
}

void splitBiggestStack(SortedSet<Integer> coinStacks){
    int coinStack = coinStacks.last();
    coinStacks.remove(coinStack);
    coinStacks.add(coinStack/2);
    coinStacks.add(coinStack/2 + coinStack%2);
}
```

Ok, next paragraph.

> So the input for this problem is a number n and then n numbers describing initial heights of those stacks. Then there is a number 1<=q<=5*10^5 which denotes number of queries. Each query consists of one number 1<=k<=10^9. So we have q queries, respectively: k_1, k_2,..., k_q and we know that the sum of those numbers is less or equal the number of possible moves until end condition. For number k_1 we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after k_1 moves. For number k_2 we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after next k_2 moves, and so on.

So we have:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> coinStackSplittingProblem(SortedSet<Integer> coinStacks, ArrayList<Integer> queries){
    //n = coinStacks.size(), q = queries.size()
    assert(queries.length >= 1, "Too few queries");
    assert(queries.length <= 500000, "Too many queries");
    for(int query:queries){
        assert(query >= 1, "Too small query");
        assert(query <= 1000000000, "Too large query");
    }
    assert(queries.stream().sum() <= coinStacks.stream().sum(), "Too large total query");

    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(queries.size());

    int qSum = 0;

    for(int query:queries){
        int count = qSum;
        qSum += query;
        while(count++ < qSum)
            splitBiggestCoinStack(coinStacks);

        results.add(coinStacks.stream().distinct().count());
    }

    return results;
 }
```

Now that we have actual code, we can try to optimize it, per the golden rules of optimization: (1) don't do it unless you need to, (2) don't do it yet, and (3) don't do it until you have test results telling you what to optimize.

Now do tests, figure out what needs optimization, and optimize it; if you have a decently good computer, this probably won't even be necessary: 1 second and 256 MB of RAM should be plenty.

(If I were optimizing this, I'd guess the main time killer is the `SortedSet`, which I would replace with a `PriorityQueue`.)